# Prior Art on 2022/0168762

Tags: prior-art, patent-applications

I am familar with CO2 snow cleaning.  In section 0006 they state "conversion of liquid
CO2 into CO2 snow only takes place in a mixing chamber in which liquid CO2 is expanded into a carrier gas which is also supplied."  The implication that a carrier gas is always needed.  ACP nozzles require a carrier gas.  Yet, in US Patent [4,806,171](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4806171A/en?oq=4%2C806%2C171) Whitlock demonstrated an efective CO2 nozzle that does'nt need a carrier gas and still can remove submicron particles.  Plus, that nozzle was a Lavel (asymmetric venturi) design.  Does this prior art negate the claims presented here?  They are doing a multi stage expansion over many steps.  Whitlock just had two steps.  I think the Patent office should ask them about Whitlock.

[US20220168762A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20220168762A1/en?oq=us%202022%2F0168762)

Answer (score 0):

I think your quote is a bit ambiguous. Here is the full sentence:

> From WO 02/075799 A1 and also from U.S. Pat. No. 7,762,869 B2,
> non-generic devices for generating a CO2 snow jet are known in which
> the phase conversion of liquid CO2 into CO2 snow only takes place in a
> mixing chamber, in which liquid CO2 is expanded into a carrier gas
> which is also supplied.

I don't read this as stating that conversion of liquid CO2 to CO2 snow only takes place with a carrier gas, as you state, but is so in the cited documents.

This isn't my field, but Whitlock is clearly relevant. However, my reading of claim 1 of US20220168762A1 shows a different nozzle configuration from Whitlock so Whitlock doesn't necessarily invalidate US20220168762A1. Based on the number of citations of Whitlock, I would highly doubt the patent examiner would overlook it when evaluating patentability of the application. Just because Whitlock doesn't use a carrier gas doesn't mean another invention couldn't.